# git add remote in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

the .gitmodule file have the list of submodule url and path, similar to this

```
[submodule ".vim/bundle/subRepo"]
    path = .vim/bundle/subRepo
    url = https://git.com/sub/repo
```

and in the .git/config of core repo have list of remotes

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@otherRepo.com
```

when

```
 git submodule init
 git submodule update
```

I get the submodules.

how add one time the list of remotes in a submodule ?
for not write everytime

```
git remote add remoteAlias git://...
```

in each submodule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I begin this command

https://github.com/juanpabloaj/git-remote-init

for save the remotes in a .gitremotes file

Answer (score 3):

```
git clone --recursive
```

or

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

if you already cloned.

Comment: but , "git submodule update --init --recursive" is for recursive pull ?

Comment: no. when you pull, you are only acting on that repository. Try `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull --rebase`. The rebase is optional.