# git: manage multiple remotes in a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-remote

My team uses a publicly available github hosted project as a submodule in our main project. We would like to manage our own patches against that project, without pushing upstream, but then we can't share those patches unless we have a mirror where we push our private branch.

Assuming we have the mirror, our submodule needs two remotes: one where we fetch upstream changes from, and one where we push merges with our patch branch. How can we store the information about the remotes with the submodule (or with the superproject), so that, every member of the team can trivially perform an upstream update, without having to `git add remote upstream ...github...project.git`.

We intend to solve the problem by writing a shell script to automate the process and a file for storing the upstream remotes, but is there a *git way* of doing this?

May be related, but I don't see a proper solution: [git add remote in submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589391/git-add-remote-in-submodule)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317365/multiple-urls-of-git-submodule-per-remote-submodules

Comment: The linked question is about managing different remotes in different checkouts by means of relative URLs, which is not related to my issue. I wish to manage two remotes per submodule in every checkout of the parent repo, *automatically*. My own answer provides our current approach which is not automatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current *ansatz* is this:

- For each submodule that needs to be managed in the above-described way, have a `submodule/.gitupstream` file store the url
- With a simple shell script:

  - update the submodule's *upstream* remote from this file
  - git fetch upstream
  - git checkout known submodule patch branch (possibly from .gitmodules submodule..branch)
  - git merge upstream/master (or whichever refspec)

Then manually:

- git push origin (the mirror containing our patch branch)
- commit changed submodule and push in the superproject

I'd like to see a better, possibly git built-in solution though.